# Loading an application in background

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am working on a C# windows forms application. I am using tab controls and have used the panel control to open an external application within my application using a button. What I want is to load the external application in my Form.Load event. Application starts at Tab1 and the external application is on Tab2.

Comment: Show what you have. It sound like you have that already for a panel so using a tabpage instead of a panel sounds easy.

Comment: @Ralf My program consists of different Tabs. I have implemented the method to use a panel on one of those tabs and it works fine. 

Code:
IDSS = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\IDSS.lnk");
                SetParent(IDSS.MainWindowHandle, this.Panel_ServiceFunctions.Handle);
                IDSS.WaitForInputIdle();
                while (IDSS.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    IDSS.Refresh();
                }

I would want this tab to load in the background while my Form.Load() displays my main form.